# Does English have a word for "bunch of random things"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there have any word that meaning "bunch/collection of random things(videos, images, clips, anything)"?

like in Chinese, there's a word called "狗屎爛蛋",

If you throw this word into google translator you will get "Shit bastard",

but what it really means behind this word is "bunch/collection of random things".

Comment: In some uses 'smorgasbord' might suit, although its context usually conveys *some* commonality (food selection at a buffet, songs on an album, cetera groupings) that usually are not strictly random.

Comment: ,,'hodgepodge'.

Comment: I haven't seen that word before but obviously it's relatively common: 
https://lengusa.com/sentence-examples/smorgasbord

Comment: 'assortment', 'medley', 'miscellany'.    lol at "shit bastard".

Comment: In biostatistics one can use [_sample_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_(statistics)) .

Comment: [eclection](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eclection)

Comment: hoard, amass, collection. variety grouping

Comment: composition, disarray, pattern.  bunch, aggregation, stockpile. (large )smattering[/s].

Comment: aggregate, heap, combination, bounty. If the assortment has particular theme (away from 'miscellany'), then a more precise word might fit, such as one of 'array' or 'sample' or 'ordering'.

Comment: stuff, things, crap, items, objects, random material, arbitrary collection, nounz (things &or ideas).

Comment: cluster, clutch, lot.

Comment: There's a *lot* of possible words that could be used here. Could you perhaps narrow down what you're looking for a bit? Perhaps adding some example sentences would help.

Comment: heahay @cigen, as it happens *lot* was the directly preceding word that I suggested! ;~]

Answer (score 1):

The word "ragbag" may fit, defined as:

> A miscellaneous collection

([Source](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ragbag))

or

> a confused mixture of different types of things

([Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ragbag))

Comment: +1 ---a word that specifically denotes (albeit at def 2 of 2) "miscellaneous collection"! that can come in handy. As too can its more connotative optional sense of "confused mixture of ..".   It also seems to convey a similar sense as how the Chinese literal-to-English translation might be used.